# ORA-00933: SQL Command not properly ended Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Hello i got a Problem i alway get the same Error. In SQL itself it works but not in Java unfortunately

```
   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl wurde nicht korrekt beendet
```

My Code:

```
    import java.sql.*;  
class verbindung2{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
//step1 load the driver class  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

//step2 create  the connection object  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//pgbtf-cluster-test.company.de:1521/pgbtf.company.de","testuser","test123");    
//step3 create the statement object  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

//step4 execute query  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select DOK_ID , ID, AKTEN_ID , TITEL , DOK_TYP , DOK_ART , ERSTELL_DAT , EING_DAT , DOK_MIME_TYPE from patgbmf.supi where DOK_MIME_TYPE='application/pdf' , OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  

//step5 close the connection object  
con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}  
}
```

Comment: You have a comma before the `OFFSET`.

Comment: I removed it but i still get the same error

Comment: Is the `;` creating problems?

Comment: Which version of oracle is that? 11? offset is not supported before 12

Comment: @VeselinDavidov ok then it must be 12 or newer i can do it that statement in Oracle SQL Developer without problems

Comment: It's not the syntax error, but I would expect an `ORDER BY` somewhere in there for it to make sense.

Comment: What do you encounter when you issue `SQL> desc patgbmf.supi` from the schema which you use for connection to the application. If successful, can you see all the columns which are seen in the `select` list ?

Comment: Remove a ';' from the query like this:ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select DOK_ID , ID, AKTEN_ID , TITEL , DOK_TYP , DOK_ART , ERSTELL_DAT , EING_DAT , DOK_MIME_TYPE from patgbmf.supi where DOK_MIME_TYPE='application/pdf' , OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY");

Comment: Thanks it works there was a ; to much :D

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too.
This can be solved by removing the semicolon at the end of the query statement. The semicolon will be added automatically during execution and Oracle does not accept the resulting duplicate semicolon.
check [here](https://help.livelyapps.com/documentation/display/PQKB/How+to+solve+Oracle+exception+ORA-00933%3A+SQL+command+not+properly+ended)